# dataTable.editable; addData function not working correctly

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my database I have consultant table that has the consultant ID and ConsultantName and another table weekly hours that has consultant ID has FK and stores hours worked by each consultant in a week. I am using jQuery DataTables Editable plug in in client-side mode to display a table with consultantName, week, hours, billableRateRt etc. 
The inline edit functionality of the table works perfectly but when I add a new row to the table I get this error

**DataTables warning (table id = 'myDataTable'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source**

The new row is added to the weekly hours table. I think the error is because of the reason that consultant name is not part of the weeklyHours. I get the consultant name by joining weeklyhours and consultant table. So I added following property to my weeklyhour model class so that I can set this property in the addData function as well before adding the new row

```
[NotMapped] public string ConsultantName { get; set; }
```

Following is the addData function

```
 public int AddData(string ConsultantName, string week, string hours, string BillableRateRT, string BillableRateOT, string PayableRateRT, string PayableRateOT, string currency)
   {

       DateTime wek = Convert.ToDateTime(week);
       var cc=db.Consultants.First(d => d.ConsultantName.ToLower().Equals(ConsultantName.ToLower())).ConsultantID; 
       var consu = from ww in db.WeeklyHours
                   where (ww.ConsultantID == cc && (ww.Week.Year == wek.Year && ww.Week.Month == wek.Month && ww.Week.Day == wek.Day))
                   select ww.ConsultantID;
       if (consu.Any())
       {
           Response.Write(ConsultantName + " work hours for"  + week + "' already exists");
           Response.StatusCode = 404;
           Response.End();
           return -1;

       }

       var weeklydata = from q in db.WeeklyHours
                        select q;
       var wh = new WeeklyHour();
       wh.ConsultantID = cc;

       wh.ConsultantName = ConsultantName;

       wh.Week = Convert.ToDateTime(week);
       wh.Hours = Convert.ToInt32(hours);
       wh.BillableRateRT = Convert.ToDecimal(BillableRateRT);
       wh.BillableRateOT = Convert.ToDecimal(BillableRateOT);
       wh.PayableRateRT = Convert.ToDecimal(PayableRateRT);
       wh.PayableRateOT = Convert.ToDecimal(PayableRateOT);
       wh.Currency = currency;
       db.WeeklyHours.Add(wh);
       try
       {
           db.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(e);
           // Provide for exceptions.
       }

       return wh.ConsultantID;
   }
```

Still I am getting the same error every time I add a row.Also I think its imp to mention that when I refresh the table I see the consultant name field has correct data.

Following is the code for initializing the Datatable

```
`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: "/DataEntry/UpdateData",
      sAddURL: "/DataEntry/AddData"

    });

});
```

```
    <div id="formSelection">
<table id="myDataTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>
                ConsultantName
            </th>
            <th>
                Week
            </th>
            <th>
                Hours
            </th>
            <th>
                BillableRateRT
            </th>
            <th>
                BillableRateOT
            </th>
            <th>
                PayableRateRT
            </th>
            <th>
                PayableRateOT
            </th>
            <th>
                Currency
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr id="@item.ConsultantID">

                <td>@item.ConsultantName
                </td>
                <td>@item.Week.ToShortDateString() @*to get date only*@
                </td>
                <td>@item.Hours
                </td>
                <td>@item.BillableRateRT
                </td>
                <td>@item.BillableRateOT
                </td>
                <td>@item.PayableRateRT
                </td>
                <td>@item.PayableRateOT
                </td>
                 <td>@item.Currency
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="add_delete_toolbar" />`
```

Following is the code that creates the add data form

```
   @{
   IQueryable<string> ConsultantNameList = DropdownUitility.getConsultantsforCompany(Model);

}

    <form id="formAddNewRow" action="#" title="Add Weekly Hours for a Consultant">
 <label for="name">ConsultantName</label>
  <select name="ConsultantName" id="ConsultantName">
   @{
     int count = 0;
    // String name = null;
     foreach (var name in ConsultantNameList)
     {
         count++;

       <option value= "@name.ToString()" id="@count" rel="0">@name </option>
     }
   }`</select>
 <br />
   <label for="name">
   Week</label><input type="text" name="Week" id="Week" rel="1" />
  <br />
   <label for="name">
    Hours</label><input type="text" name="Hours" id="Hours" rel="2" />
  <br />
    <label for="name">
   BillableRateRT</label><input type="text" name="BillableRateRT" id="BillableRateRT"
       rel="3" />
  <br />
   <label for="name">
   BillableRateOT</label><input type="text" name="BillableRateOT" id="BillableRateOT"
       rel="4" />
   <br />
   <label for="name">
   PayableRateRT</label><input type="text" name="PayableRateRT" id="PayableRateRT" rel="5" />
    <br />
   <label for="name">
   PayableRateOT</label><input type="text" name="PayableRateOT" id="PayableRateOT" rel="6" />
   <br />
   <label for="name">
   Currency</label><input type="text" name="Currency" id="Currency" rel="7" />
   <br />
   <br />
    </form>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug, it was the rel attribute in the html selectList for ConsultantNames.

WRONG :

```
  <select name="ConsultantName" id="ConsultantName">
   @{
     int count = 0;
     foreach (var name in ConsultantNameList)
     {
         count++;

       <option value= "@name.ToString()" id="@count" rel="0">@name </option>
     }
   }
  </select>
```

select should have the rel attribute which the editable plugin uses to match data to column. In my previous code I put the rel attribute in the Options tag which was wrong.

CORRECT:

```
     <select name="ConsultantName" id="ConsultantName" rel="0">
   @{
     int count = 0;
     foreach (var name in ConsultantNameList)
     {
         count++;

       <option value= "@name.ToString()" id="@count" >@name </option>
     }
   }
    </select>
```